# Grab instagram photo based on hashtags

Tags: instagram, hashtag

I am new to instagram and i am tasked to program an application to grab instagram photo uploads based on a certain hashtag. Meaning if the application is started and searching for the hashtag "#awesomeevent" any one that uploads a photo with that hashtags it will automatically be stored into our database.

The application should work something similar to http://statigr.am/tag/ but instead displaying the photos it should store the photos into the database.

What is the process of doing this. Any tutorials that has this from start to end. Even covering how to start creating a instagram app from scratch. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Things we developers often overlook are the API Terms and Conditions. I've been there myself.

> API TERMS OF USE
>
> Before you start using the API, we have a few guidelines that we'd like to tell you about. Please make sure to read the full [API Terms of Use](http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)
>
> Terms of Use. Here's what you'll read about:
>
> - Instagram users own their images. It's your responsibility to make    sure that you respect that right.
> - You cannot use the Instagram name in your application.
> - **You cannot use the Instagram API to crawl or store users' images    without their express consent.**
> - You cannot replicate the core user experience of Instagram.com
> - Do not abuse the API. Too many requests too quickly will get your    access turned off

However, a part in the terms also states that:

> - You shall not cache or store any Instagram user photos other than for reasonable periods in order to provide the service you are
>   providing to Instagram users.

Hope that's a start before you actually get coding and storing images.

API Terms of Use: http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/

API: http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Bhavik while this is true, i'm not sure Instagram would have an issue with storing the returned JSON only in a local file / database and then querying the stored JSON instead. No actual images are stored and all data still refers to Instagram, however you would need to refresh this cache every 10-15 minutes or so, or possibly run a background process to fetch new data into the cache periodically.

Answer (score 1):

For starter, you should consult to [instagram api](http://instagram.com/developer/).

As for the specific api you will need is:

```
/tags/tag-name/media/recent
```

For example, if you want to look for images from tag `#awesomeevent`, you will do an api query to:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/awesomeevent/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: However, how do i create a application to do that instead of typing the URL.

Comment: @BryanChew : you could use jQuery.ajax to read the json file generated by that URL. Just make sure you use `dataType: "jsonp"`

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at the two libraries Instagram provides. The ruby library is at https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem and the python library is at https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

They both seem to have examples to get you started if you're programming with either libraries.

As far as the storing issue goes, could you instead store the URL address of the images instead of the actual images themselves? The API returns JSON information of which the URL of the images are returned.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below ruby script to retrieve the images and save them to a file. You can then either reference the file within the database or replace the last block with code for your particular database implementation. Without knowing your database type and schema, no one can tell you how to add something to it.

```
require "instagram"
require "restclient"

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID 
  config.client_secret = INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET
end

instagram_client = Instagram.client(:access_token => INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN)
tags = instagram_client.tag_search('cat')
urls = Array.new

for media_item in instagram_client.tag_recent_media(tags[0].name)
  urls << media_item.images.standard_resolution.url
end

urls.each_with_index do |url, idx|
  image = RestClient.get(url)
  path = Dir.pwd + "/#{idx}.jpg"
  File.open(path, 'w') {|f| f.write(image) }
end
```

Comment: not working now, cause Instagram doesn't return hashtag photos